# PHP's DOMDocument node:is it possible to get its absolute position?

Tags: php, string, domdocument

Let me explain a bit more:

Let's say I have a string containing a XML or HTML document. I can load this string to a DOMDocument and access any of its node using for example getElementsByTagName method.

Is it possible to know what is the position of this node in the original string? How about its end position?

I tried but not able to find any node's property or method to accomplish that but it looks too obvious to me that the class knows this information and could easy return it to me upon my request. Isn't it?

Comment: Are you saying the want the node's ordinal position in the scope of the entire document tree?

Comment: @prodigitalson I'd better say not in a tree but in original STRING

Comment: If you mean like you would get if you ran an `strpos` on the initial string then no. I'm not sure why the DOM would even care about that; The structure of the initial string is pretty irrelevant once you have a parsed document. Furthermore, I'm pretty sure that is not in any of the DOM level specifications so this shouldn't be unique to PHP's DOMDocument. Perhaps you could clarify why you need this information, there may be a better way to accomplish your goal or a workaround if you definitely need it.

Comment: @prodigitalson, I'd like to use both approaches to parse the document: DOM approach and use my own algorithms working with initial string using functions like stripos. Initailly I have troubles getting the node value without it's child contents.

Comment: Seems like you have a specific question in there - `Initailly I have troubles getting the node value without it's child contents.` So i would revise this question, or post a new question regarding that at this point. Make sure to include example code. I will say that my initial impression is that this endeavor is folly, you're essentially attempting to build `libxml` on the PHP side instead of jsut using one of the PHP interfaces for it (DOMDocument, XMLReader, SimpleXML) so unless you have a **really good reason** for wanting to do this id say you're wasting your time ;-)

Comment: @prodigitalson, actually I think that the possibility to combine both DOM-oriented and stright `stripos` approaches could be very interesting. So maybe you're right saying that I should use different approach to the specified task (and I probably post this questin as you've recomended) but I still think that this question has it's right to be asnwered.

Comment: Im not sying it doesnt have a right to be answered just that 1.) youre essentially trying to recreate functionality of a an existing, robust c library (libxml2) for parsing on the php side which seems like insanity to me, and 2.) that detailing how you would go about #1 is a huge thing so it would be better to post about the specific question you had when trying to parse the string yourself because there is no way to get the str position from within the php xml interfaces.